# Connecting guitar to mixer and pc

Tags: mixer, guitar, troubleshooting

I bought a guitar and an amp, and to connect my guitar to the pc I followed some guides on the internet. Looking for a good setup I got a BEHRINGER Xenyx 302 mixer and a BEHRINGER DI100 DI with the necessary cables, but my setup doesn't work.

I connected the guitar to the DI box, then the DI to the mixer's mic in and the output from the mixer to the mic in on the pc. I can hear some background noise but nothing from the guitar. I tried to connect to a speaker instead of the pc and I just can hear background noises but nothing from the guitar. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Everything about your signal chain sounds correct except for the mixer to the pc. It sounds like you want to use your mixer as an interface, in which case you'd want to use the USB to connect to your pc, not the speaker output.

Once connected, you'll need software on the pc to be able to record. You could go the freeware route and get Audacity, but there are lots of options out there. I believe Presonus still offers Studio One Artist which was free in the past, though limited in functionality.

Comment: Thank's brian for your answer,i downloaded audacity but it recordes only background noises...i also tried to connect the guitar to the ampli and the audio out of the ampli to the di box and nothing changes

Comment: What you'll need to do is get the proper drivers installed on your pc for the mixer to act as an interface. What I recommend is following the instructions outlined in the user manual of the Mixer as this process can be different for just about any device.

Comment: @Francesco but did you use the USB connection instead of the mic in? (For the mixer to computer). That's the important part here. Also... you have the gain, fader, and master levels turned up, right?